# Converting SQLite database column values to strings and concatenating

Tags: python

I have a database with the following format.

(1, 'Kristen', 'Klein', '2002-11-03', 'North Cynthiafurt', 'AZ', '50788')

I am trying to strip away the first and last name values and pass them to a function to concatenate them as strings. "Kristen Klein" in this case.

I use a query such as:

```
query_first = db.select([customer.columns.first_name])
proxy_first = connection.execute(query_first)
result_first = proxy_first.fetchall()
print(result_first)
```

to extract all the first name values and they come out like this:
[('Kristen',), ('April',), ('Justin',)]

I use an identical one for the last names and get an identical output.

This syntax is confusing to me as it appears to be a dictionary (?). How do I convert these to strings so that I may concatenate them into a cohesive name?

Comment: This `[('Kristen',), ('April',), ('Justin',)]` - is a list of tuples.

Comment: If you are familiar with sqlite, you can adjust your query to get the values of both first and last name like this `SELECT firstname,lastname FROM tablename;` and you will have a output like this `[('firstname', 'lastname'), ('Kristen', 'Klein'), ... ]`

Comment: Revise the question whether you are using `sqlalchemy` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `[('Kristen',), ('April',), ('Justin',)]` - is a **list of tuples**. If you are confused by the trailing comma after string, because it is required to distinguish it as a `tuple` for **single element** tuple's.
Find out the full info here in [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax).

I guess you were using `sqlalchemy` library to connect to the db. If so by selecting the `last_name` with your `first_name` would provide you with a `result_set` list at the end which is *iterable* in a `for loop`. So, by *concatenating* each `tuple` would give you the `full name`. Please find the changes below,

```
#input
query = db.select([customer.columns.first_name, customer.columns.last_name])
result_proxy = connection.execute(query)
result_set = result_proxy.fetchall()

for row in result_set:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

```
#output
Kristen Klein
Peter Parker
Tony Stark
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also [concatenate](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html?highlight=concat#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.concat) on the query level:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import  functions as func

query = db.select(
    func.concat(
        customer.first_name, ' ', customer.last_name
    )
)
results = connection.execute(query).all()
```

Or write raw SQL:

```
raw_sql = """
    SELECT
        first_name || ' ' || last_name
    FROM
        customer
"""

results = connection.execute(raw_sql).all()
```

Comment: Have  you tried this yourself? SQLite does not understand `func.concat`

Answer (score 0):

There are some `SQLAlchemy` utilizing answers here. In that case:

SQLite don't understand `func.concat`, you have to use string addition operators.

```
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast

query = db.select(cast(customer.columns.first_name, String) + " " + cast(customer.columns.last_name, String))
```